# Docker Angular Support for VS 2017

Tags: angular, visual-studio, docker

Why can't we have the angular support in VS 2017?

What is the missing part?
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even though it is not enabled by default for an angular project.You can enable by

- Right click project in the solution explorer
- Hover over add Click
- Docker support

[image]